# Showing all rows from both master tables in many-to-many without CROSS JOIN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is the sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cd936/5

This is the rest of the query:

```
CREATE TABLE Farmers (
  FarmerName NVARCHAR (50)
  );

CREATE TABLE Animals (
  AnimalName NVARCHAR (50)
  );

CREATE TABLE FarmerAnimals (
  FarmerName NVARCHAR (50)
, AnimalName NVARCHAR (50)
, Qty        INT
  );



INSERT Farmers (FarmerName) VALUES ('Jane'), ('Andrew'), ('Bob')
INSERT Animals (AnimalName) VALUES ('Goat'), ('Horse'), ('Elephant')
INSERT FarmerAnimals (FarmerName, AnimalName, Qty) VALUES ('Jane', 'Goat', 10), ('Jane', 'Elephant', 3), ('Jane', 'Elephant', 1), ('Andrew', 'Horse', 5), ('Bob', 'Goat', 1), ('Bob', 'Goat', 1)

SELECT
  f.FarmerName
, a.AnimalName
, Qty = SUM (ISNULL (fa.qty, 0))
FROM
  Farmers f
CROSS JOIN Animals a
LEFT JOIN FarmerAnimals fa ON
    fa.FarmerName = f.FarmerName
AND fa.AnimalName = a.AnimalName
GROUP BY f.FarmerName, a.AnimalName
```

Is there any way to rewrite the `SELECT` query not to use `CROSS JOIN` ?

Comment: Why don't you want a `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: I'd like to understand other alternatives and to be more specific: avoid the Nested Loop (with no Join Predicate) operator

Comment: Given the table structure you provided and your goal, a list of all animals  for all farmers, no, there is no way to do this without a cross join.

Comment: try do it with nested queries

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by regular `INNER JOIN`, but there is probably near 100% that behind the scene these 2 queries will provide identical execution plans:

```
SELECT
  f.FarmerName
, a.AnimalName
, Qty = SUM (ISNULL (fa.qty, 0))
FROM
  Farmers f
INNER JOIN Animals a ON 1 = 1
LEFT JOIN FarmerAnimals fa ON
    fa.FarmerName = f.FarmerName
AND fa.AnimalName = a.AnimalName
GROUP BY f.FarmerName, a.AnimalName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below instead of cross join.

FROM
  Animals a
inner join Farmers f
on f.FarmerName <> a.AnimalName

Answer (score 0):

If you need all farmers and animal to show even if they don't have FarmerAnimal records, you will have to use CROSS JOIN. Otherwise a normal JOIN would do but showing only Farmers/Animals that have records in FarmerAnimals

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your SQLFiddle might show; it won't load for me. But if you want all farmer names and all animal names, regardless of whether there's a matching row in "FarmerAnimals", I'd write this in standard SQL. (I inserted another row in Farmers and in Animals, so we can clearly see the effect of the outer join.)

```
select f.FarmerName, a.AnimalName, sum(coalesce(fa.qty, 0)) as TotalQty
from Farmers f
full outer join FarmerAnimals fa
  on f.FarmerName = fa.FarmerName
full outer join Animals a
  on a.AnimalName = fa.AnimalName
group by f.FarmerName, a.AnimalName
order by f.FarmerName, a.AnimalName;
```

```
FarmerName  AnimalName          TotalQty
--
Andrew      Horse                5
Bob         Goat                 2
Jane        Elephant             4
Jane        Goat                10
Joe Bob                          0
            Horse-sized duck     0
```

And, to make that work in SQL Server, I think all you need to do is replace the expression `sum(coalesce(fa.qty, 0)) as TotalQty` with `sum(isnull(fa.qty, 0)) as TotalQty`. SQL Server 2005+ supports full outer joins.

I don't have any way to test whether full outer joins avoid nested loops in SQL Server (which a comment says you're interested in), but PostgreSQL's query planner uses "Hash Full Join".

Comment: unfortunately - those w/ 0  doesn't show up - ie:

Andrew Elephant 0, Bob Elephant 0

Comment: No, those won't show. Is that something you show in the SQLFiddle? (Still won't load for me--503 error.)

Comment: yes, Mike - the returned dataset is part of the SQLFiddle. and yes - you're right: seems SQLFiddle is playing up.

Comment: @YS: Sorry to have misled you then. I haven't been able to use SQLFiddle for months. Even when the page loads, it usually won't let me build a schema.